# Uniform convergence of sequence of function necessary for switching limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence

If a sequence of function $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ uniformly, we know that we have
$$\lim_{t\to x}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{t\to x}f_n(t)$$

My question is: Is uniformly convergence necessary for the above to hold?

Comment: What is the domain of these functions?

Comment: I am learning real analysis. So let's say some subset $E$ of real numbers, and $x$ is any limit point of $E$.

Comment: If the $f_n$ are continuous, it reduces to $\lim_{t \to x} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$. So you are asking if $f(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(t)$ is continuous at $x$. And for that, the uniform convergence on an interval containing $x$ is sufficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose on $[0,1]$ we set $f_n(t) = nt(1-t)^n.$ Then $f_n(t) \to 0$ pointwise on $[0,1].$ Let $x=0.$ Then

$$\lim_{t\to x}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{t\to x}f_n(t).$$

But since $f_n(1/n) = (1-1/n)^n \to 1/e, \,f_n$ fails to converge uniformly to $0$ in every $[0,\delta].$

Comment: So please allow me to conclude. Your functions satisfy $\lim_{t\to x}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{t\to x}f_n(t)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, but fail to converge uniformly in $[0,1]$. Hence it is a counterexample to show that uniform convergence is not a necessary condition.

Comment: Right. The main point, though, was to find a limit point $x$ of $E$ such that $f_n$ fails to converge uniformly on any neighborhood of $x.$

Answer (score 4):

Uniform convergence is not necessary, consider e.g. $f_n(t)=t^n$ and $x=0$.

However, if $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$, there may still be some $x$, for which the equality fails to hold, e.g. same example as above with $x=1$.

Comment: What if I require it to hold for all limit points $x$? Then is uniform convergence necessary?

Comment: Still not: just consider the same example restricted to $[0, 1)$.

Comment: That's kind of cheating because your $f_n$ are uniformly convergent in a neighborhood of $0.$

Comment: But they are not uniformly convergent on $[0, 1)$. No one said they couldn't converge uniformly on proper subsets.